# Logging data into log files using log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Hi I have a requirement to write entries into log files coming from table in MySQL. I did my research, but did not get satisfied on the solutions I found. I read about using log level as debug to check whether the sql query is running correctly or not.

But I want the data to be logged into the specific log file which does not log anything else, just the data from the sql tables. Can anyone help ?

Here is the code that I have written as a POC. This is my class part.

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogDemo.class.getName());
private static final Marker QUERY_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("SQL");

public static void main(final String... args) {

// Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
    logger.info("Ankush Bhan created this");
    logger.error("THIS IS TRACE");


}
```

And this is my configuration log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">C:/Users/712054/Desktop/Source</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="info" fileName="${log-path}/info.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
                 <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
                 <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>

    <Root level="info" >
      <AppenderRef ref="info"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run this, both the statements are getting printed. But I want only log.info part ??

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I tried using simple log.info to log into the log files and in the configuration file I put filters to just log the info part. But is there any other way we can do ?

Comment: It seems that the simple solution of reading from the mysql table using jdbc and logging it using log4j2 should work. Log4j2 can be configured to write logs into a separate file for this class/logger. Any complications?

Comment: Should I use filters to make that work ?

Answer (score 0):

So i finally solved the issue by using filters only. Here is the java class that prints some message into the log file. And in another log file I add trace messages. This is the configuration file I edited.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">C:/Users/712054/Desktop/Source</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="info" fileName="${log-path}/info.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1"/>
      </Policies>

    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="trace" fileName="${log-path}/trace.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
         <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>

             <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1"/>
      </Policies>

    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>

    <Root level="all" >
      <AppenderRef ref="info"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="trace"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And the corresponding java class is

```
public class LogDemo {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogDemo.class.getName());


    public static void main(final String... args) {
    logger.entry(); //this goes in the trace log file
    // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
        logger.info("This goes only in the info log file");
        logger.trace("This goes only in the trace log file");
        logger.exit(); //this goes in the trace log file


    }
```